# Trying to open a new cmd window then run multiple commands in it

Tags: batch-file, colors, command-prompt

I am facing a rather annoying issue when trying to write a batchscript file for my assignment, the assignment asks me to open a new command prompt window, change its color and make it print the current windows version. I can make it open the new window and change the color but no matter what I do it will always execute any new commands including the ver command on the old command prompt window, I have tried using & to run multiple commands but it just does nothing.

```
start cmd /k color F1 & ver
pause
```

This is the code I have now, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To undertake the task you've specifically shown us, there is no need whatsoever to use the `color` command, and as a result, include an ampersand to join two commands.

If you open a Command Prompt window, type `cmd.exe /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should see that there is a `/T` option you can use.

```sh
Start %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /T:F1 /D /K Ver
```

Comment: T for `Tint` perhaps?

Comment: @Magoo, did you learn that from tinternet!

Comment: @Magoo `T` could be also derived from just `text` or `text attribute` because of the Windows console function [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) is used to set text color and background color with the 16-bit [character attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes) bit mask attributes value. We would need to ask for clarification [Rich Turner](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/author/richturn/), Senior Program Manager, Windows Console & Command-Line.

Comment: [Windows Command-Line: Unicode and UTF-8 Output Text Buffer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/) is a very interesting developer blog written by Rich Turner.

Comment: @Mofi : Given his responses so far to `cmd` improvement suggestions, and the visible results of implementning those suggestions (ie. no extra/improved commands) , I'm in no doubt that unfortunately such an exercise would be a complete waste of time.

Comment: I had never come across anything using those / options that's really interesting and will definitely be useful for questions further down the line in the assignment thank you for that I will note those down.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
start "My assignment" cmd /k "color F1 & ver"
```

Note that the window title is the first quoted string in the `start` command.

Answer (score 1):

Without double quotes only the "color f1" command is being passed to your new cmd window.

```
start cmd /k "color F1 & ver"
pause
```

I think will give you the results you want.

Comment: That did it, thank you very much for your help